# How to calculate mouse coordinate in percent javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mouseevent

I have starting coordinate and end coordinate of the element, how can I know the percent move.

Code

```
element.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
                event.preventDefault();
                start(e);
            });
function start(e){
  start = e.clientX,
  width = element.innerWidth();
  $document.bind('mousemove', dragging);
}
function dragging(e) {
    var offset = start - e.clientX;
    console.log(offset); // In Px
}
```

How can I convert offset into the percent?

Say start point is 10 and end point is 90
then pixel movement is 80px and percent movement is 10%

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the percentage change, which is `(endPoint-startPoint)/startPoint x 100`.

```
function dragging(e) {
    var percentageChange = (e.clientX - start)/start * 100;
    console.log(percentageChange); // In Px
}
```